# Selecting from line number x to xxx in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

Let's say I have a 500,000 line file, how do I select from line 200,000 to 350,000 in sublime text? I just need to delete all those lines, it's pretty tedious doing the highlight scrolling.

Is there a command I can put into the command line? I can't seem to find anything on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why open this file and do it in ST?  If you know which lines you want to delete, just use `sed`.

```
sed -i -e '200000,350000d' filename
```

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! I've never used sed before. Thank you, will definitely bookmark this.